# MPI Send is giving segmentation fault

Tags: c++, boost, mpi, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to run a genetic algorithm with MPI(boost), in which I have to send a serialized object from rank 0 to all other ranks. But I'm getting an error of segmentation fault when I try to send data.

Here's the code, output and the error I'm getting.

Code: the problem is exactly in world.send(0, 0, newP);

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) 
{
    Population *pop = NULL;
    RuckSack r(true);
    int size, rank;
    Ga ga;
    namespace mpi = boost::mpi;
    mpi::environment env;
    mpi::communicator world;

    int countGeneration = 0;

    /* code */

    if (world.rank() == 0)
    {

        if (pop == NULL)
        {

            pop = new Population(60,true);
        }

    }

    for (int m = 0; m < 20; m++)
    {
        /* code */

        for (int i = 0; i< world.size(); i++)
        {
            world.send(i,0,pop);
        }


        world.recv(0, 0, pop);
        Population newP = *pop;


        newP = ga.evolvePopulation(newP, world.size());




        world.send(0, 0, newP);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Error:

```
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 10336 on node user exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
```

Output:

```
[user:10336] *** Process received signal ***
[user:10336] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[user:10336] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[user:10336] Failing at address: 0x31
[user:10336] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x35860)[0x7f1e93064860]
[user:10336] [ 1] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so.1.61.0(+0x14a24)[0x7f1e9409da24]
[user:10336] [ 2] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so.1.61.0(+0x15d11)[0x7f1e9409ed11]
[user:10336] [ 3] ./teste(+0x1de7c)[0x55ab4c07ae7c]
[user:10336] [ 4] ./teste(+0x1dd2c)[0x55ab4c07ad2c]
[user:10336] [ 5] ./teste(+0x1db3a)[0x55ab4c07ab3a]
[user:10336] [ 6] ./teste(+0x1d8eb)[0x55ab4c07a8eb]
[user:10336] [ 7] ./teste(+0x1d2da)[0x55ab4c07a2da]
[user:10336] [ 8] ./teste(+0x1cb20)[0x55ab4c079b20]
[user:10336] [ 9] ./teste(+0x1bed0)[0x55ab4c078ed0]
[user:10336] [10] ./teste(+0x1b47c)[0x55ab4c07847c]
[user:10336] [11] ./teste(+0x19741)[0x55ab4c076741]
[user:10336] [12] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7f1e9304f3f1]
[user:10336] [13] ./teste(+0x112aa)[0x55ab4c06e2aa]
[user:10336] *** End of error message ***
```

---

Comment: I am assuming your logic is allowing you to try send a null pop pointer. You only allocate the Population object if "world.rank() == 0" so it is likely that world.rank() != 0. Let me know if so, will make answer.

Comment: I suggest you take into account the feedback from the helpful answer and re-post the question with a proper [mcve] (read that page very carefully!). Also document your own debugging attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some wild guesses:

1. You should only do the initial send instruction on a rank0 process - right now you perform it an all of the processes which doesn't make sense (and might be a cause of the problem)
2. You should not send to "self". In the first iteration of you loop, the rank0 does a send to itself, which afaik will block the process waiting for a recv. But since the rank0 is blocked it will never reach the 'recv' line and will remain locked forever. Apart from that it again doesn't make sense for a process to send data to itself.

Those are just loose suggestions as i have a limited experience in using MPI. Hope it helps!

Comment: These are very good points - you shouldn't downplay that as *wild guesses*. However, none of those explain a segfault.

Comment: You were right, I fixed the initial send instruction - it didnt make sense, indeed, my bad :/. it didnt solved the problem, but it helped me very much. Thank you for that :)